# Как сменить bg-image при нажатии на элемент (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет:) Новенький в этой сфере, так что не обессудьте. Верстаю что-то типа плеера, есть кнопка play и при нажатии, её сменяющая - pause. В интернете нашёл не одно решение, но что-то базовое и простое из того, что я пробовал, к сожалению, не подошло.

```html
<div class="music-box-2">
  <a href="#" id="play" class="musicIcon playTest"></a>
</div>
```

```js
let playTest = document.querySelector('playTest');
let play = document.getElementById('play');
play.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.playTest.style.backgroundImage = url('../img/pause.png');
});
```

Comment: `document.playTest.style` ► `playTest.style` (ведь `playTest` это переменная, а не свойство объекта `document`). Ну и селектор в первой строке неправильный, не хватает точки перед именем класса... изучи теорию про CSS (методы `querySelector[All]`, `matches`, и т.д. - используют именно css-селекторы).

Comment: Классы и id, кстати, регистронезависимые... поэтому слова в них чаще разделяют дефисом, типа `class="music-icon play-test"` (ну вот как у `div` в примере). А сам код вроде норм, то есть он должен заработать если указанные ошибки исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Первая ошибка

```
let playTest = document.querySelector('playTest'); <-
let play = document.getElementById('play');
play.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.playTest.style.backgroundImage = url('../img/pause.png');
});
```

В `.querySelector` и `.querySelectorAll` указывается селекторы, как в CSS, т.е. `.class`, `#id`, `tag` и т.п. [Подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
Должно быть

```
let playTest = document.querySelector('.playTest');
```

---

### Вторая ошибка

```
  let playTest = document.querySelector('.playTest');
  let play = document.getElementById('play');
  play.addEventListener("click", function () {
->  document.playTest.style.backgroundImage = url('../img/pause.png');
  });
```

Вы вначале уже нашли этот элемент в `document`е, повторный поиск не нужен
Должно быть:

```
playTest.style.backgroundImage = url('../img/pause.png');
```

---

### Третья ошибка

```
let playTest = document.querySelector('.playTest');
let play = document.getElementById('play');
play.addEventListener("click", function () {
  playTest.style.backgroundImage = url('../img/pause.png'); <-
});
```

Тут вы должны передать строку с CSS правилом.
Должно быть:

```
playTest.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'../img/pause.png\')';
```

---

### Четвёртая ошибка

Ну и когда вы "почините" код, запустите, вы столкнётесь с другой ошибкой, при нажатие на ссылку у вас скролл переместится наверх страницы из-за `href="#"` у вашей ссылки.
Варианта два: 1. переделать `A` в `DIV` (например). 2. запретить `A` выполнять переход по `href` атрибуту, его и рассмотрим:

```
let playTest = document.querySelector('playTest');
let play = document.getElementById('play');
play.addEventListener("click", function () {
  playTest.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'../img/pause.png\')';
  return false; // Этого хватит, чтобы отменить переход
});
```

---

### Демо кода

```js
let playTest = document.querySelector('.playTest');
let play = document.getElementById('play');
play.addEventListener("click", function () {
  playTest.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'//i.imgur.com/KVOlqKD.png\')';
  return false;
});
```

```css
#play {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/0K47nDu.png') no-repeat center center / contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="music-box-2">
  <a href="#" id="play" class="musicIcon playTest"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Как классно, что существует такая возможность, задать вопросы специалистам, которые уже с этим сталкивались. Аж вдохновляет учиться дальше, когда существует такое комьюнити, еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @De.Minow, спасибо, все по сути работает. Но как я понял у меня проблемы с путем до картинки, ибо выдает в консольке это - GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/img/pause.png 404 (Not Found). Иерархия такая - https://ibb.co/Fqn7F3r

Comment: @onelevalde, попробуйте путь `/img/pause.png`.

Comment: спасибо, заработало при таком варианте - img/pause.png